# How to update images when theme changes in uwp

Tags: c#, uwp

According to docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/images-tailored-for-scale-theme-contrast#updating-images-in-response-to-qualifier-value-change-events) I should use this code:

```
    var qualifierValues = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().QualifierValues;
    qualifierValues.MapChanged += new Windows.Foundation.Collections.MapChangedEventHandler<string, string>(QualifierValues_MapChanged);
```

to update images when qualifier items are changed. However when I am changing theme in system settings this event is not fired. How I am supposed to react to Theme changes then?

Comment: Kind of. I am surprised that qualifierValues does not work, and solution with ThemeLister is nasty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Theme Listener** class from Windows Community Toolkit allows you to determine the current Application Theme, and can listen the changes of System Theme. When you change the System Theme in setting, it will trigger the ThemeChanged event. Before you use this class, you need to add **Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI** Nuget package. About more details, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/themelistener).

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    var Listener = new ThemeListener();
    Listener.ThemeChanged += Listener_ThemeChanged;
}

private void Listener_ThemeChanged(ThemeListener sender)
{
    var theme = sender.CurrentTheme;
    //Update your images
}
```